# Recursion Coin Change problem gives wrong answer

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Why does my code, print out "Found Solution" 7 times inside of 4 times when the coins are [1,2,3] the change in cents is 4. There should only be 4 possible solutions. What did I do wrong here?

```
def coinChange(nCents, coins, total):
    if (total == nCents):
        print("Found solution")
        return 
    if (total > nCents):
        return
    if (total < nCents):
        for i in range(len(coins)):
            coinChange(nCents, coins, total+coins[i])

coins = [1,2,3]

coinChange(4, coins, 0)
```

Comment: First of all, you should print out each solution as you find it.  Secondly, you are probably getting permutations of the solution:  `[3,1], [1,3], [2,2], [2,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,1,1]` so you should either sort your solutions or never use a coin greater than the last coin added.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused shouldn't the next coin that is added be greater so the list will be ordered ?

Comment: You should start with the greatest coin applicable, and work your way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct answer to *why* can be found by keeping track of the coins you have used and printing them with the results. That will make clear why you are getting seven results:

```
def coinChange(nCents, coins, total, coin_list = None):
    if coin_list is None:
        coin_list = []
    if (total == nCents):
        print("Found solution", coin_list)
        return 
    if (total > nCents):
        return
    if (total < nCents):
        for i in range(len(coins)):
            coinChange(nCents, coins, total+coins[i], coin_list + [coins[i]])

coins = [1,2,3]

coinChange(4, coins, 0)
```

This prints:

```
Found solution [1, 1, 1, 1]
Found solution [1, 1, 2]
Found solution [1, 2, 1]
Found solution [1, 3]
Found solution [2, 1, 1]
Found solution [2, 2]
Found solution [3, 1]
```

As you can see, this gets this result because it considers solutions like `[1, 1, 2]` `[1, 2, 1]` and `[2, 1, 1]` to be distinct.

Comment: thank you soo much, what is the best way to avoid duplicates results but still have infinite coins for each time it picks?

Comment: You could pass a slice back into the recursion: `coinChange(nCents, coins[i:], total+coins[i], coin_list + [coins[i]])` Understanding why that works is not immediately obvious, but interesting.

Comment: @Mark if try passing sliced array, would you still get 1, 1, 1, 1, as a solution ?

Comment: @DanielHao how exactly? what do I do differently on reach recursive call?

Comment: @sam202252012 Yes (as well as `[1, 1, 2]` and `[2, 2]`), but you should not take me word for it…try it.

Comment: It's easier to see the running code. Would you?

Comment: @Mark I tried it worked, So I'm guessing on each call the variations to try are smaller and since the first call is [0:] then 1, 1, 1, 1 still gets printed right?

Comment: Exactly @sam202252012! It will keep doing that until it meets one of the other gates -- it either equals the target or it got too big.

Comment: Thank you soo much Mark, this really helped me out. Also even when you slice the array the first variation of each combinations still gets to run right hence why it works?

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT the direct answer to the PO.  But it's rather to show another way - *Dynamic Programming* way to solve the same problem:

```
def coin_ways(coins, amount):
    dp = [[] for _ in range(amount+1)]
    
    dp[0].append([])      # or table[0] = [[]], if prefer

    for coin in coins:
        for x in range(coin, amount+1):
            dp[x].extend(ans + [coin] for ans in dp[x-coin])
    #print(dp)
    
    return dp[amount]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    coins = [1, 2, 3]  # 
 
    print(coin_ways(coins, 4))
```